# Spring MVC - hot to populate dropdown from a manytoone relation

Tags: spring, jsp

Good morning all.
Today I have a problem in populating a dropdown menu with values from a related table in the db.

I have a Luci table and a Client table. Client table as a ManyToOne relation with a column in Luci.

In my LuciController I have this method to create the JSP for the new Luce

```
@Controller
public class LuceController {
    String path = "light";

    @Autowired
    LuceService luceService;

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/light/new" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newLight(ModelMap model) {
        Luce luce = new Luce();
        List<Client> clients = clientService.findAllClients();
        model.addAttribute("luce", luce);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("clients", clients);
        return path + "/registration";
    }
    // controller continues...
```

List clients = clientService.findAllClients() works good with the ClientController I have to display all the clients.

When I have to render the form in JSP i have problems to get the dropdown menu to have che clientId as value and clientName as item do display

My registration form is:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="luce">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="idLuce" id="idLuce"/>
        <table>
        <tr>
                <td><label for="numeroLuce">Numero Luce: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="numeroLuce" id="numeroLuce"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="numeroLuce" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="nomeLuce">Descrizione: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="nomeLuce" id="nomeLuce"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="nomeLuce" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td><label for="client.nomeClient">Client: </label> </td>
                <td><form:select path="client">
                <form:options value="${client.idClient}" items="${client.nomeClient}"/> </form:select></td>
                <td><form:errors path="client" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
```

I have no error while running the page, but the dropdown is empty... Obviously the table Client has records...

My question is: which is the best way to solve this situations? I have to pull out the idClient as a value and the nomeClient as the item to display...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`<form:options value="${client.idClient}" items="${client.nomeClient}"/>`

should be

`<form:options itemValue="idClient" itemLabel="nomeClient" items="${clients}" />`

Supposing `idClient` and `nomeClient`  are fields in  the class Client.

Comment: The original answer was incorrect, I have corrected this.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect, I have understood a new thing today!

Comment: Sorry @AlanHay but now we have a different problem.